# NSMenuitem tempelate image tint color not changing

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have customview which has image view image i'm setting `NSImageNameMenuOnStateTemplate` to imageview with tint color but tint color is not applying

```
NSImage *tintImage = [self tintedImage:[NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameMenuOnStateTemplate] withTintColor:NSColor.whiteColor];

myimageView.image = tintImage
```

```
-(NSImage*)tintedImage:(NSImage*)image withTintColor:(NSColor*)color{
    NSImage *tinted = [image copy];
    [tinted lockFocus];
    [color set];

    NSRect imageRect = {NSZeroPoint, [image size]};
    NSRectFillUsingOperation(imageRect, NSCompositingOperationSourceAtop);
    [image unlockFocus];
    return tinted;
}
```

Any help most appreciated ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `[image unlockFocus];` with `[tinted unlockFocus];`

for macOS you need to set `setTemplate` to `NO`

```
[tinted setTemplate:NO];
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You really should avoid using lockFocus/unlockFocus. They're deprecated and you've misused them by locking one image and unlocking another. Use `+[NSImage imageWithSize:flipped:drawingHandler:]

As a category addition to NSImage:

```
- (NSImage *)imageWithSolidFillColor:(NSColor *)color
{
    return [NSImage imageWithSize:self.size flipped:false drawingHandler:^BOOL(NSRect dstRect) {
        [self drawInRect:dstRect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositingOperationSourceOver fraction:1.0];
        [color set];
        NSRectFillUsingOperation(dstRect, NSCompositeSourceAtop);
        return YES;
    }];
}
```